# GAMS Optimization Using loops

Tags: loops

Im answering an optimization problem. Which is running the below model 10 times, each time using a different desired return rate as given in a table. I need to record the corresponding optimal standard deviation values and fill the blanks.
•The expected (quarterly) return rate is at least 0.03
Xi <= 0.3
•The standard deviation of the portfolio’s return rate is minimized.

Im[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZCwr.png) getting an error in the blow code shown in a screenshot. What am i doing wrong?

```
$TITLE Mean-variance model.

* MeanVar.gms:  Mean-Variance model.
* Consiglio, Nielsen and Zenios.
* PRACTICAL FINANCIAL OPTIMIZATION: A Library of GAMS Models, Section 3.2
* Last modified: Apr 2008.

SET Assets /APPL, GOLD, SBUX, F/;

ALIAS(Assets,i,j);

PARAMETERS
         ExpectedReturns(i)  Expected returns  /APPL 0.0480625, GOLD -0.0238125, SBUX  0.0220625, F  0.0045000 /;

table
         VarCov(i,j)
              APPL          GOLD         SBUX             F
APPL  2.471529e-03 -0.0010721458 1.241958e-04 -1.396667e-05
GOLD -1.072146e-03  0.0016157625 7.590542e-04  1.618333e-04
SBUX  1.241958e-04  0.0007590542 9.847292e-04  1.203333e-05
F    -1.396667e-05  0.0001618333 1.203333e-05  2.010667e-04
;



* Risk attitude: 0 is risk-neutral, 1 is very risk-averse.;

SCALAR
    lambda Risk attitude /0.9/;


POSITIVE VARIABLES
    x(i) Holdings of assets;

VARIABLES
    PortVariance Portfolio variance
    PortReturn   Portfolio return
    z            Objective function value;

EQUATIONS
    ReturnDef    Equation defining the portfolio return
    VarDef       Equation defining the portfolio variance
    NormalCon    Equation defining the normalization contraint
    ObjDef       Objective function definition;


ReturnDef ..   PortReturn    =e= SUM(i, ExpectedReturns(i)*x(i));;

VarDef    ..   PortVariance  =e= SUM((i,j), x(i)*VarCov(i,j)*x(j));

NormalCon ..   SUM(i, x(i))  =e= 1;

ObjDef    ..   z             =e= (1-lambda) * PortReturn - lambda * PortVariance; 

MODEL MeanVar 'PFO Model 3.2.3' /ReturnDef,VarDef,NormalCon,ObjDef/;



MeanVar('Assets') = 0.3;
display  MeanVar;

solve m2 min cost using lp;

set trial /trial1*trial10/;
parameter optimal_std(trial);
optimal_std(trial) = 0.3 + (ord(trial)-1)*0.1;
parameter values(trial);

loop(trial,
    ('Assets') = optimal_std(trial);
    solve m2 min values using lp;
    values(trial) = value.1;
  )  
;

solve MeanVar max z using qcp;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  59  MeanVar('Assets') = 0.3;
****        $143      $148
**** 143  A suffix is missing
**** 148  Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less
****         indices as declared
  60  display  MeanVar;
****                 $143
**** 143  A suffix is missing
  61   
  62  solve m2 min cost using lp;
****         $140,241 $140      $257
**** 140  Unknown symbol
**** 241  Model has not been defined
**** 257  Solve statement not checked because of previous errors
  63   
  64  set trial /trial1*trial10/;
  65  parameter optimal_std(trial);
  66  optimal_std(trial) = 0.3 + (ord(trial)-1)*0.1;
  67  parameter values(trial);
  68   
  69  loop(trial,
  70      ('Assets') = optimal_std(trial);
****      $767,409
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
**** 767  Unexpected symbol will terminate the loop - symbol replaced by )
  71      solve m2 min values using lp;
****             $241       $243      $257
**** 241  Model has not been defined
**** 243  Objective is not a variable
**** 257  Solve statement not checked because of previous errors
  72      values(trial) = value.1;
****                           $342,140,315,409
**** 140  Unknown symbol
**** 315  Unknown suffix - ignored
**** 342  Illegal suffix syntax - has to start with a letter
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
  73    )
****    $408
**** 408  Too many ),] or }
  74  ;
  75   
  76  solve MeanVar max z using qcp;
****                               $257
**** 257  Solve statement not checked because of previous errors

**** 18 ERROR(S)   0 WARNING(S)
```

That is 18 syntax errors in 13 lines of code. That is quite an achievement.

```
  59  MeanVar('Assets') = 0.3;
****        $143      $148
**** 143  A suffix is missing
**** 148  Dimension different - The symbol is referenced with more/less
****         indices as declared
```

This is not even close to GAMS syntax. I am not sure what it means given that MeanVar is a model identifier, and Assets is a set. Let's just get rid of it.

```
  62  solve m2 min cost using lp;
****         $140,241 $140      $257
**** 140  Unknown symbol
**** 241  Model has not been defined
**** 257  Solve statement not checked because of previous errors
```

There is no m2 model. Obviously, that cannot work. The only model we have a meanVar (which is not an LP). So, I suggest deleting this also.

```
  70      ('Assets') = optimal_std(trial);
****      $767,409
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
**** 767  Unexpected symbol will terminate the loop - symbol replaced by )
```

Obvious this is not even close to GAMS syntax. No idea what the meaning of this is, so I deleted it.

```
  71      solve m2 min values using lp;
****             $241       $243      $257
**** 241  Model has not been defined
**** 243  Objective is not a variable
**** 257  Solve statement not checked because of previous errors
```

This was discussed earlier. There is no m2 and there is no LP model. I deleted it.

```
  72      values(trial) = value.1;
****                           $342,140,315,409
**** 140  Unknown symbol
**** 315  Unknown suffix - ignored
**** 342  Illegal suffix syntax - has to start with a letter
**** 409  Unrecognizable item - skip to find a new statement
****        looking for a ';' or a key word to get started again
```

There is no identifier value in the model. As suffix .1 is not legal GAMS. I deleted it as this has no meaning.

The remaining errors are the result of earlier ones. So a correct model can look like:

```
$TITLE Mean-variance model.

* MeanVar.gms:  Mean-Variance model.
* Consiglio, Nielsen and Zenios.
* PRACTICAL FINANCIAL OPTIMIZATION: A Library of GAMS Models, Section 3.2
* Last modified: Apr 2008.

SET Assets /APPL, GOLD, SBUX, F/;

ALIAS(Assets,i,j);

PARAMETERS
         ExpectedReturns(i)  Expected returns  /APPL 0.0480625, GOLD -0.0238125, SBUX  0.0220625, F  0.0045000 /;

table
         VarCov(i,j)
              APPL          GOLD         SBUX             F
APPL  2.471529e-03 -0.0010721458 1.241958e-04 -1.396667e-05
GOLD -1.072146e-03  0.0016157625 7.590542e-04  1.618333e-04
SBUX  1.241958e-04  0.0007590542 9.847292e-04  1.203333e-05
F    -1.396667e-05  0.0001618333 1.203333e-05  2.010667e-04
;



* Risk attitude: 0 is risk-neutral, 1 is very risk-averse.;

SCALAR
    lambda Risk attitude /0.9/;


POSITIVE VARIABLES
    x(i) Holdings of assets;

VARIABLES
    PortVariance Portfolio variance
    PortReturn   Portfolio return
    z            Objective function value;

EQUATIONS
    ReturnDef    Equation defining the portfolio return
    VarDef       Equation defining the portfolio variance
    NormalCon    Equation defining the normalization contraint
    ObjDef       Objective function definition;


ReturnDef ..   PortReturn    =e= SUM(i, ExpectedReturns(i)*x(i));;

VarDef    ..   PortVariance  =e= SUM((i,j), x(i)*VarCov(i,j)*x(j));

NormalCon ..   SUM(i, x(i))  =e= 1;

ObjDef    ..   z             =e= (1-lambda) * PortReturn - lambda * PortVariance;

MODEL MeanVar 'PFO Model 3.2.3' /ReturnDef,VarDef,NormalCon,ObjDef/;



*MeanVar('Assets') = 0.3;
*display  MeanVar;

*solve m2 min cost using lp;

set trial /trial1*trial10/;
parameter optimal_std(trial);
optimal_std(trial) = 0.3 + (ord(trial)-1)*0.1;
parameter values(trial);

loop(trial,
*    ('Assets') = optimal_std(trial);
*    solve m2 min values using lp;
*    values(trial) = value.1;
  )
;

solve MeanVar max z using qcp;
```

This is all very disappointing.